# Odoo - Magento 2 connection issue

Tags: magento, odoo, odoo-8, magento2

I am trying to establish communication between odoo and magento using the magento odoo connector. Odoo V8 and Magento 2.1.2 are running on 2 different servers using vagrant, so far i have been able to install the connector on odoo by following the [installation guide](http://odoo-magento-connector.com/guides/installation_guide.html),
it is right after that where things started to seem ambiguous.
Odoo server: 192.168.33.11:8069
Magento server: 192.168.33.12
see below the connector configuration interface:

[image: Configuration form]

```
2016-11-06 14:01:55,850 1842 ERROR magentodoo openerp.addons.magentoerpconnect.magento_model: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/vagrant/packages/connector-magento/magentoerpconnect/magento_model.py", line 214, in synchronize_metadata
    import_batch(session, model, backend.id)
  File "/vagrant/packages/connector-magento/magentoerpconnect/unit/import_synchronizer.py", line 382, in import_batch
    importer.run(filters=filters)
  File "/vagrant/packages/connector-magento/magentoerpconnect/unit/import_synchronizer.py", line 251, in run
    record_ids = self.backend_adapter.search(filters)
  File "/vagrant/packages/connector-magento/magentoerpconnect/unit/backend_adapter.py", line 211, in search
    [filters] if filters else [{}])
  File "/vagrant/packages/connector-magento/magentoerpconnect/unit/backend_adapter.py", line 159, in _call
    full_url=custom_url) as api:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/magento/api.py", line 150, in __enter__
    self.username, self.password)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1233, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1587, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1273, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1321, in single_request
    response.msg,
ProtocolError: <ProtocolError for magento:M4g3nt0@192.168.33.12/index.php/api/xmlrpc: 404 Not Found>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Magento 2 ships with a SOAP and REST based API. There is no longer an
>   XML-RPC based API.

In order to established connection with magento 2 you need such additional details (REST API)....

```
Consumer Key (customer_key)
Consumer Secret (customer_secret)
Access Token (token)
Access Token Secret (secret)
```

Example (create client to send request and get response)

```
import oauth2 as oauth
consumer = oauth.Consumer(key=customer_key, secret=customer_secret)
token = oauth.Token(key=token, secret=secret)

client = oauth.Client(consumer, token)
```

Once you get the client then you can send request to magento.

```
data = NONE
api_url =  'VALID API URL'
headers = {'Accept': '*/*', 'Content-Type': 'application/json','Authorization':'Bearer %s'%token}
resp, content = client.request(api_url, method='GET/POST', body=json.dumps(data),headers=headers)
```

[Click here for detailed connection theory](http://magento-quickies.alanstorm.com/post/142036931270/magento-2-understanding-the-web-api-architecture)